# Access two dimensional Array's element in Scala (Processing in Apache-Spark)

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib, recommendation-engine

I am now trying to get Cosine Similarity.

There is also an item list, which consists of Array[(Int, Int)].

```
  val list = Array(Array((item_11, item_12), (item_13,item_14), (item_15,item_16),  ...
                   Array((item_21, item_22), (item_23,item_24), (item_25, item_26), ...
                   ...

                   Array((item_n1, item_n2), (item_n3,item_n4), (item_n5, item_n6), ... ))
```

And I want to get the Cosine-Similarity between the items (item_1, item_2) using Feature vectors that extracted from ALS Model by accessing each element of the array.

The output that i want,

```
Array( similarity from item_11, item_12 ), ...
Array( similarity form item_21, item_22), ...
```

And I processed some code but spark doesn't support nested RDDs, So I failed.
The code was,

```
val combinations = list.mapValues(_.toSeq.combinations(2).toArray.map{ case Seq(x,y) => (x,y)}).map(_._2)


val simOnly = combinations.map{_.map{ case (item_1, item_2) =>
val itemFactor_1 = modelMLlib.productFeatures.lookup(item_1).head
val itemFactor_2 = modelMLlib.productFeatures.lookup(item_2).head
val itemVector_1 = new DoubleMatrix(itemFactor_1)
val itemVector_2 = new DoubleMatrix(itemFactor_2)
val sim = cosineSimilarity(itemVector_1,itemVector_2)
sim}}
```

Could anybody Help me to fix this?